# Bring max value from a table based on the values of another table with PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have two Spark DataFrames, the first one (`Events`) contains events information as following:

| Event_id | Date | User_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-04-19 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-05-30 | 2 |
| 3 | 2020-01-20 | 1 |

The second one (`User`) contains information from users as below:

| Id | User_id | Date | Weight-kg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-04-05 | 78 |
| 2 | 1 | 2019-04-17 | 75 |
| 3 | 2 | 2019-10-10 | 50 |
| 4 | 1 | 2020-02-10 | 76 |

What I wonder to know is how to bring the latest value of weight from `User` before the `Event Date` using PySpark?

The return of this code must be the following table:

| Event_id | Date | User_id | Weight-kg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-04-19 | 1 | 75 |
| 2 | 2019-05-30 | 2 | null |
| 3 | 2020-01-20 | 1 | 75 |

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I need the latest value of weight before the Event Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is left join events and users then ranking the weight based on dates to get the latest ones

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(event
    # left join to keep all events
    # note the join condition where
    # event's date >= user's date
    .join(
        user,
        on=[
            event['User_id'] == user['User_id'],
            event['Date'] >= user['Date'],
        ],
        how='left'
    )

    # rank user's weight to get the latest
    # based on the dates that already filtered by event's date
    .withColumn('rank_weight', F.rank().over(W.partitionBy(user['User_id']).orderBy(User['Date'].desc())))
    .where(F.col('rank_weight') == 1)
    .drop('rank_weight')
 
    # drop unnecessary columns
    .drop(user['User_id'])
    .drop(user['Date'])
    .drop('Id')


    .orderBy('Event_id')
    .show()
)

# Output
# +--------+----------+-------+------+
# |Event_id|      Date|User_id|Weight|
# +--------+----------+-------+------+
# |       1|2019-04-19|      1|    75|
# |       2|2019-05-30|      2|  null|
# |       3|2020-01-20|      1|    75|
# +--------+----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I replace the orderBy from Weight to User['Date'].desc() it works perfectly!